# Quickest way to assign each value of list to a value of another list

Tags: c#, performance, collections

If say, we have a list with serial numbers and another list with products, which is the quickest (and more elegant) way to assign one serial number to each product?

Can use the classic:

```
 var serialNumbers = CreateSerialNumbers().ToList();
 var index = 0;
 foreach (var product in Products)
 {
     product.SerialNumber = serialNumbers[index];
     index++;
 }
```

or `for`

```
for (int index= 0; index < Products.Count; index++)
{
    Products[index].SerialNumber = serialNumbers[index];
}
```

but are there quicker/more elegant ways? Maybe with Linq?

Comment: LINQ really is just a series of `foreach` statements anyway, either of your solutions are fine.

Comment: I think that `for` loop is as fast as you're going to get, and it's only 2 lines. But why are you skipping the last product in the `for` version?

Comment: @RufusL was a mistake. I had first "<=" instead of "<" and forgot to delete the -1..

Comment: Remember that the `Q` in LINQ stands for *query*, it's meant to read data, not change it.

Comment: This will initialize a list of `Product` for each serial number: `var products = Enumerable.Range(0, serialNumbers.Count).Select(index => new Product {SerialNumber = serialNumbers[index]}).ToList();`

Comment: Here it looks like either `for` or `foreach` is fine, but looking at your design it looks to me there is a way to 'improve' your code. When you generate a bunch of serial numbers using `CreateSerialNumbers()`, I'm assuming you're going through some sort of a loop anyway. So, if you are allowed to change the method, pass a `ref` of your `Products` list and assign the serial number at the moment it's created. Avoids looping through the list twice. Just an idea.

Comment: What does `CreateSerialNumbers()` return?  An `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Are you concerned with speed or elegance?

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException is coming soon...

Comment: @maccettura yes an IEnumerable, but was just an example.

Comment: @gunnerone both, maybe two different solutions.

Comment: @Ali Bah....why?

Comment: again a "debatable" downvote...

Comment: @RafaGomez what happens if the count of `Products` is not the same as the count of `serialNumbers`?

Comment: @maccettura in this case yes. But it's my job to take care of that and assure that they are always the same. Like I said it was just an example...I could pass just an int to CreateSerialNumbers and voilá...

Comment: @RafaGomez ok, so why not just create a method `IEnumerable<Product> AssignSerialNumers(IEnumerable<Product> products)` ?  Then just loop through each `Product` and assign it a serial number, then return the modified collection?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
for (int index= 0; index < Products.Count; index++)
{
    Products[index].SerialNumber = serialNumbers[index];
}
```

...but you need to make sure `serialNumbers[index]` is not out of bounds as well. Maybe...

```
for (int index= 0; index < Products.Count; index++)
{
    if(serialNumbers.Count >= index
         Products[index].SerialNumber = serialNumbers[index];
    else
         index = Products.Count;
}
```

That isn't really the safest thing to do, but it will work here.

Comment: Based on some of the comments from the OP I dont think this is the best approach anymore...